# What is the range of convergence of the series (a) $\sum a^{\sqrt{n}}x^n$ and (b)$\sum n^{\frac{\log n}{n}}x^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the range of convergence of the series (a) $\sum a^{\sqrt{n}}x^n$ and (b)$\sum n^{\frac{\log n}{n}}x^n$?

My solution:
(a) $L=\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a|^{\sqrt{n}}}=\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a|^{\frac{\sqrt{}n}{n}}=1$, for all $a \in \mathbb R$. Then the range of convergence is $r=\frac{1}{L}=1$.

(b) $L=\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|n|^{\frac{\log n}{n}}}=\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}|n|^{\frac{\log n}{n^2}}=1$,then the range of convergence is also $1$.
Thank you!

Comment: You're correct, but how do you know that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} n^{(\log n)/n^2}$ equals $1$?

Comment: Hello, Greg! That's because $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{log n}{n^2}=0$

Comment: Hi :) But that's not a valid argument. It proves that $c^{(\log n)/n^2}$ tends to $1$ for any constant $c$ (by continuity of the function $c^x$, for example); but $n$ is not a constant here. In fact, this limit is an indeterminate form "$\infty^0$", so one needs to look harder to decide what its limit is.

Comment: I agree. Do you have any suggestion on how to evaluate this limit?

Comment: Yep! Anytime you have an indeterminate form with an exponent, take logarithms. That turns it into a $0\cdot\infty$ form, which you know how to handle (l'Hopital's rule, for example). Here, what is $\log(n^{(\log n)/n^2})$? What's its limit as $n\to\infty$? What's exp(that limit)?